# Temperature to bake/warm up a pumpkin pie that isnt frozen

Tags: baking, temperature, pie, pumpkin, warming

Temperature to cook/warm up a store bought pumpkin pie that is not frozen.

Comment: It has already been cooked also

Comment: Pretty sure pumpkin pie is usually served cold

Answer (score 1):

Pumpkin pie is normally served at room temperature, so leaving it on the counter for a few hours should suffice. If you want to warm it slightly, 15 minutes uncovered in a 140°C oven followed by sitting on the counter for another 10 minutes should be sufficient.

To check whether it's been warmed through to your liking, here's an easy way to check the inner temperature of a thick piece of food: insert the tines of a fork straight down into the middle, leave them there for a few seconds, then remove the fork and hold the tines just over your lips. If you don't sense any heat coming off the tines, touch them to your lips. (If you're sure the food's not too hot you can jump straight to the second part, but otherwise you risk burning your lips.)